# page speed insight Pre-load key request for fontawesome

Tags: magento2, pagespeed-insights

On my magento 2 store, Google pagespeed insight showing below fonts in preload key request.
How to get rid of this issue.

[image]

CSS for font awesome is.

```
src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.6.3');
src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.6.3') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.6.3') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.6.3') format('woff'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.6.3') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.6.3#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
```

Comment: Any solution for this? I am also facing same issue.

Comment: Didn't found any solution but after using Amasty Google page Speed extension this error was gone.